# Cannot connect to server using filezilla with portnumber

Tags: 14.04, sftp, filezilla

I cannot connect to server using fileZilla  using a specific port but it connect without port number on same application. My question is why i cant connect with port number. I tried to connect via `sftp` with port number then it is ok. So i guess its not the problem with port number. How i can rectify this issue. I am using ubuntu 14.04 and my FileZilla version is 3.7.3.

This is the error showing while connecting with port number

```
Status: Resolving address of xyz.sample.com
Status: Connecting to 123.45.5.7:222...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+hetzner1
Error:  Cannot establish FTP connection to an SFTP server. Please select proper protocol.
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Answer (score 4):

As your error log says:

```
Error:  Cannot establish FTP connection to an SFTP server. Please select proper protocol.
```

SFTP and FTP are different protocols!

SFTP uses an SSH connection in the background. Just because this works does not allways mean automatically that you can use the FTP protocol to connect to it since FTP is not secured.

Make sure you have an FTP-Server installed on the server machine.

#### Alternative

Instead you could choose the SFTP Option in the connection settings of FileZilla.

[image: Choose "SFTP" as Protocol, "normal" as Logon Type and provide your login data]

Also make sure you choose not "Anonymous" but "normal" as Logon Type and provide valid login data.